# How to open year firstly then month and then date when bootstrap calender is opened

Tags: jquery, configuration, bootstrap-datepicker

I am making an application and need to choose DOB for user profile. I am using bootstrap datepicker for DOB field but I need to open year first then month and date for date of birth(DOB).

Here is my config code:-

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
   calendarWeeks: true,
   todayHighlight: true,
   autoclose: true,
   format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
});
```

Please let me know the configuration which will help me out.

Comment: Use 'yyyy-mm-dd' format and go through http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ which will help you.

Comment: I am not talking about about the date format. I am talking about the datepicker window. Like firstly I will choose year then month and after that date.

Comment: Have you gone through the link which i have provided. there they have provided demos related to date selection.<input size="16" type="text" value="2012-06-15 14:45" readonly class="form_datetime">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});
</script>  use this code with css changes(Include css changes in your local and check ) .

Answer (score 4):

Add [`startView: 2`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startview) in the configuration

```js
$('#dob').datepicker({
    calendarWeeks: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    startView: 2
});
```

Comment: If your changes to the js file don't work at first, remember to hard-reload the page and clear the cache.